# Users should make use of their privileges

Tags: discussion, post-quality, privileges

The issue with this website is that we have merely 25 users with reputation > 200.

Still as the site is in public beta, users get access to [important privileges](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) with less reputation compared to sites which are graduated.

The reason am saying this is, that new users will register who will probably question or answer which may be off topic or low quality. Leaving the questions just like that, *(without editing, close voting)* will increase the low quality post count thus degrading the overall quality of the site.

**Why I posted this question?**

I've seen many times that users with decent reputation do visit the post, but they don't edit if required, no retags, and also no close vote, an example of this can be seen here...

- [Who considered as Ultimate God?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/726/)

  *I want to know who is considered ultimate god? In other words who has Ultimate Supernatural Power?*

Now first of all is the title, which is grammatically incorrect isn't edited by the users. Editing won't matter much over here as the question seems unclear and should be closed voted.

But some users don't vote to close, now obviously this is a opinion based thing whether to close vote or not but the above question is totally *unclear*.

Here, user *Keshav Srinivasan* <sup>(no personal targeting, just an example)</sup> commented but didn't vote to close, so make sure that as a privileged user, you should use the functionality provided to you by Stackexchange.

This applies even after the moderators are appointed, they will be 3 but you cannot rely totally on them for cleaning up the posts here and editing them out. Also, moderators cannot close vote a question straight away, unless the post is too offensive or spam in nature.

So make sure you keep using your tools regularly and wisely. Feel free to answer if anyone has a different views over this.

You can do following activities for which you are having privileges for whenever and wherever required, but again, use your tools wisely :

- Close questions which are off-topic, too broad, opinion based, for more information, refer questions on meta which are tagged as [scope](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope)
- Keep reviewing the posts in the review que
- Edit questions, retag them if required, rectify grammar, spell check etc
- Flag comments which you might feel are spam, offensive, rude, too chatty
- Flag questions and answers if they spam, are offensive in a way, or users posting comments as an answer, or answering to reply other comments incase of insufficient commenting privileges

Comment: I also thought to say this, completely agree with you +1.

Comment: This should be featured.

Comment: Superb point of discussion, this has been worrying me for a while too! Maybe I should also contribute more. :(

Answer (score 4):

You've forgotten the most important privilege of all, the one that doesn't require >200 reputation.

I'm talking about voting.

Voting:

- Pushes good content up, and bad content down.
- Ups user retention
- Brings privileges to users

While closing and editing are important, voting is much more. Vote like there's no tomorrow!

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to share this over here, did [shared on my other answer](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se/45#45) but this is one of the important point, thanks..