# Please use the review tools to help keep the site clean

Tags: discussion, privileges

I have noticed a few times that we are unable to gather 5 votes to close a question. Few are still stuck with 4 close vote. Its not only about closing off-topic questions but other things also need to be reviewed.

[image]

As you can see above where review button stays. Clicking on it can help us maintain our quality. Click [Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) to know about it. We currently don't have our specific moderator and we can't expect community moderator to handle every little thing for us. I have seen Mr.Alien requesting Shog9 to close off topic question. But why, why this need came? If we want to make this site work then we need to give our inputs too.

*Note- Its related to [Users should make use of their privileges](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158/users-should-make-use-of-their-privileges)  but still needed to be addressed. And name indicated above are only for example.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Users should make use of their privileges](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/158/users-should-make-use-of-their-privileges)

Comment: We should not close this as duplicate. If this is coming again, it _needs_ to be addressed, not closed. Cheers!